# How to manage powershell script in task sequence (MDT)?

Tags: powershell, mdt

I have a question about running a powershell script as a task sepeunce.
My .ps1 file contains the following script:

```
powercfg /setactive 8c5e7fda-e8bf-4a96-9a85-a6e23a8c635c
```

I put the file on C:\users\desktop on the mdt server. Now I try to create a task sequence to execute the script for new devices.

When I fill in `powershell.exe -file "%ScriptRoot%\energie_highest.ps1"` and `%ScriptRoot%` the task sequence is getting a failure.

I'm still an IT-trainee. So what did I made wrong?

[image: Task Sequence]

Comment: `%scriptroot%` is not a valid parameter. You could use `%userprofile%` 0r any other variable you see when typing `set`

Comment: Hi. Can u post it as answere, so I can accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`%scriptroot%` is not a valid parameter. You could use `%userprofile%` or any other variable you see when typing `set`